# Current in a potential divider

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image: In this potential divider set up the battery emf is 18v]

I dont understand why the current in R wont be the same as that in the 50 ohms resistor. Isnt that the rule for series circuits? The emf for the battery is 18 volts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R$ is not in series with the 50 Ohm resistor. It is in series with the parallel combination of the 50 Ohm resistor and the resistance of the lamp.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The current will be divided into two parts at the junction, some going into the lamp, some going through the 50 Ohm resistor. If you considered the lamp and 50 Ohm resistor to be one component (say, by calculating their effective resistance), the total current going through that element would be the same as the current going through R.